# CakePHP 3 Reset passwords

Tags: php, cakephp, encryption, passwords

I have lost users password in my system developed using cakephp.
Is there a way to change passwords using PhpMyadmin or any other way like command line tool (We can use Tinker in laravel)

I did not change Cakephp default encryption method.

Comment: Do you mean you want to change encrypted password of particular user ?

Comment: Yes, Think I want to login to the system,
I Know username, but don't know password.
I want to reset password

Comment: Which version of cakephp you are using ?

Comment: Cake php version is v3.4

Comment: I use a command for it, see my [Setup shell](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-setup/blob/master/docs/Console/Shells.md#resetshell). You can do sth similar or leverage even that plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Well CakePHP3 Default hash algorithm use [BCrypt Hash Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt). So you can generate bcrypt hash of any string and save that in your table for particular user (as you know the username).

Eg. one of the Bcrypt hash of string 'test' would be:

```
$2a$06$j0t7MjWeEZL4ABGM0vZXJOgTgXZMPRFJTZUhkiOHzufrxVpC5chJq
```

You can generate such hash from [bcrypt hash generator](http://bcrypthashgenerator.apphb.com/?PlainText).

Answer (score 1):

You could go by Manohar Khadkas answer or you could put something like this somewhere in your app temporarily and copy/paste the result to your database.

```
$hasher = new \Cake\Auth\DefaultPasswordHasher();
debug($hasher->hash('PUT_NEW_PASSWORD_HERE'));
```